# PutSQL PG with MERGE go in success but it doesn't apply the changes in the DB

Tags: sql, apache-nifi

I'm trying to create a PG in NIFI that implements the following MERGE as a query:

```
MERGE INTO LIVENESS l
     USING (select ? as cdn from dual) ct 
     ON (ct.cdn = l.cdn)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
      l.LIVENESS_ENABLE  = ?, 
      l.DATETIME_LIVENESS_UPDATE  = TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
    WHERE (l.DATETIME_LIVENESS_UPDATE < TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (CDN, LIVENESS_ENABLE, DATETIME_LIVENESS_UPDATE) 
    VALUES (?, ?, TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Mapping the parameters in a PG of type UpdateAttribute set as shown in the figure:

[image]

[image]

While as far as the PutSQL PG settings are concerned, they are as follows:

[image]

The problem is that even if the PG containing the MERGE returns a success, the modifications do not affect the DB on which NIFI points. Can anyone give me some more information? Unfortunately I don't have access to NIFI logs.

Comment: Could you check by issuing the SQL `MERGE` query directly on a SQL IDE by replacing the `?` with its corresponding attributes if that seems to work as intended

Comment: We have already done this check and works